# Technical information needed on how the ISP tracks VPN

Tags: networking, vpn, privacy, isp, tracking

I've read a lot of topics about battle between ISP and VPN and they all say this :

> Your ISP cannot know what you get up to on the internet.
>       It cannot see your data because it is encrypted.
>       It cannot know what websites you visit because all internet activity is routed through the VPN server.

`Your ISP can only see that you are connected to the VPN server`.

I want a technical explanation for this point !! How they can track my VPN? If there any filtering system or ports or auto detection system for this?

Comment: What do you mean by "track"? A VPN tunnel is a regular network connection on the outside, of course it's visible. Do you want to know if a connection can be identified as a VPN connection?

Comment: yes daniel thats what i want how isp  identified a VPN connection what ports and Characteristics for this service in technical

Answer (score 1):

When you're connected to a VPN, your ISP can only tell that you're connected to a VPN server, nothing more. If you're using a public VPN service, they can probably figure out which one you're using.

If you are using a private VPN server, they can still tell you're connected to a VPN by gauging the amount of encrypted packets being transferred from your source IP to a single destination IP.

If you've configured the VPN correctly, they can't tell which websites you visit while connected to the VPN. However, if the DNS server for your VPN connection is set to your ISP's servers, they can tell which websites you visit. They still can't see what you download or upload though because that is encrypted.

You can test if your DNS servers are leaking information about you by visiting  https://dnsleaktest.com after you're connected to a VPN.

Comment: how do they can   gauging the amount of encrypted packets being transferred from my source IP to a single destination IP.
i mean is there an auto system or what or they follow firewall rules or flters etc .... i need more info man

Comment: @QassamMahmoud The ISP can use any or all of the things you mention (or indeed other methods) to analyse your data traffic. The only way to find out is to ask them ;)

Comment: @DavidPostill  they rufused to answer of course ..... is there any technical document's u may know  about the topic

Comment: @QassamMahmoud Questions seeking product, service, or learning material recommendations are off-topic.